# weird artifact appear while baking lightmap in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, noise, light, uv-mapping

I have been baking lightmaps in unity for a model and every time I bake light map weird noise appear in the baked object. I have tried generating UV's in unity and also created lightmap UV's and try to use it but still the issue remains.

these are the noises that appear in the model.
[image: image 1]    [image: image 2] [image: image 3]

Comment: Are all the faces/normals facing outwards in your modal?

Comment: yes all normals as well as faces are facing outward.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally solve the issue . You just have to go to the material of the mesh and enable double sided illumination .